# How to make a JList filling JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, jlist

I have got a `JPanel` with a `JList` added inside. How to make that that `JList` will got height and weight like my `JPanel`. It need to fill it totaly.

If i have got 2 items in my `JList`, i want to 1 of these will be 1/2 of height, if 3 - 1/3 of height etc.

Any solutions?

```
public class RozkladLotow extends JPanel{
Vector<Samolot> samoloty;
public RozkladLotow(GeneratorSamolotow g){
    super();
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    Miasto m1 = new Miasto("Warszawa",571,142,"Polska",10,10);//sample objects needed to create a `Samolot`
    Miasto m2 = new Miasto("Pekin",571,142,"Chiny",10,10);//sample objects needed to create a `Samolot`
    samoloty = new Vector<Samolot>();
    samoloty.add(new Samolot(0, m1, m2, 0, 0, 0 , 0));
    samoloty.add(new Samolot(0, m2, m1, 0, 0, 0 , 0));
    JList lista = new JList<Samolot>(samoloty);
    add(lista,BorderLayout.CENTER);     
}
}
```

Ofc in class `Samolot` i have got `toString()` functions returning sample `String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to make that that JList will got height and weight like my JPanel.
>   It need to fill it totaly.

Well in this case the solution is adding the list into a `JPanel` with [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html), as pointed out in other answers.

> If i have got 2 items in my JList, i want to 1 of these will be 1/2 of
>   height, if 3 - 1/3 of height etc.

This requirement is a little more tricky: the cell height depends on the list's visible rectangle and the number of elements in the list **or** the number of elements you want to *display*, which may be different.

For instance let's say the list has 6 elements but you only want to display a maximum of 5 cells (rows) and then scroll the list. You can do as follows:

- Use [JList.setVisibleRowCount()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setVisibleRowCount%28int%29) method to set the maximum number of cells to be displayed.
- Add a [ComponentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html) to the list to listen to the component event triggered when the list is resized: [ComponentListener.componentResized()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html#componentResized%28java.awt.event.ComponentEvent%29)
- Use [JComponent.getVisibleRect()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getVisibleRect%28%29) method to get the list's visible rectangle.
- Use [JList.setFixedCellHeight()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setFixedCellHeight%28int%29) method to set a fixed cell height.

For instance:

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
model.addElement("Fender");
model.addElement("Gibson");
model.addElement("Ibanez");
model.addElement("Paul Reed Smith");
model.addElement("Jackson");
model.addElement("Godin"); // The model has 6 elements

JList list = new JList(model);
list.setVisibleRowCount(5); // I want to show only 5 elements, then scroll the list

list.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() { // ComponentAdapter implements ComponentListener interface
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        JList list = (JList)e.getComponent();
        int divider = Math.min(list.getVisibleRowCount(), list.getModel().getSize());
        list.setFixedCellHeight(list.getVisibleRect().height / divider);
    }
});

JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
content.add(new JScrollPane(list));
```

Since I'm using [Math.min()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min%28int,%20int%29) to determine the minimum divider in order to set the fixed cell height properly, if the list model has only 2 elements they both will fill the 50% each one of the available height.

**Note:** if you want to display all the elements in the list always, then it's easier:

```
list.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        JList list = (JList)e.getComponent();
        list.setFixedCellHeight(list.getVisibleRect().height / list.getModel().getSize());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
jPanel.add(jList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
     JList<String> list = new JList<>();
     JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); 
     panel.add(list,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

If you have single component in panel, it is automatically stretch the component.

Comment: Still not working. Weight of the component is filling a `JPanel` however height ist. If i got 3 elements in list i have got 3 lines of result, if 5, 5 lines. Their are not filling all my `JPanel`